# Display data from console log

Tags: php, jquery, html

I am trying to display database into an html page. The data appears in my console but I cant figure out how to display it in an html table. I am not sure the function I need to add into console.log (data) for it to display onto to the page. This is what I have so far:

```html
    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="btn">Get Code</button>

    <table class="table table-bordered">
    <thread>
    <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>City</th>
    <th>Country</th>
    <th>Rating</th>
    </tr>
    </thread>

    <tbody id ="tdata">

    </tbody> 
   </table>

    <script>
    $(function () {

    $.getJSON("php.php", {tableName:"travel"}, function(data){
      if (data["code"] == "error"){
        console.log(data["message"]);
      }
      else{

        console.log(data);
      }
    console.log("returned hh");
    });

    });
    console.log("returned");
    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: PHPMyAdmin *is not* a database. It is a web interface for your MySQL database.

Comment: You need to share your PHP code which is getting the data from the database.

Comment: Java is not Javascript, they are different.

Comment: I removed the wrong tags. There's no Java code here and phpMyAdmin is a tool not a database.

Comment: I am trying to use jquery to get MySQL database

Comment: You're using jQuery to run a PHP script that connects to the database. You cannot directly connect jQuery to a database.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205689/discussion-between-chi-c-j-rajeeva-lochana-and-jay-blanchard).

Comment: You have the data from ajax, depending on its format (json, xml, html) you will loop through the records and insert them in an element of your page. Maybe draw a html table and append to a div. so many different ways.

Comment: This may help: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp

Answer (score 0):

Its no json structure example so you will have to replace "value.a" with the correct json values names.

After json is loaded:

```
$.each(data,function(i,value){
$('.table').append('<tr><td>value.a</td><td>value.b</td><td>value.c</td><td>value.d</td></tr>')
})
```

Hope this helps